# css - Get div to fill parent for cup bracket

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my css. I cant get the div-children of my "round"-classes to fill their parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/ubJxJ/10/

To be even more clear: I want the divs to align for a bracket-setup. F.x. "Match #17"s center is the same as the center of "Match #1" and "Match #2".

CSS:

```
#cup { display:table; }
#headlinecontainer, #roundcontainer { display:table-row; }
#headlinecontainer div {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
}
#roundcontainer .round {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:#F00;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#roundcontainer .round div.match { background-color:#0F0; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="cup">
    <div id="headlinecontainer">
        <div>Round of 32</div>
        <div>Round of 16</div>
        <div>Quarter</div>
        <div>Semi</div>
        <div>Final</div>
    </div>
    <div id="roundcontainer">
        <div class="round ro32">
            <div class="match">Match #1</div>
            <div class="match">Match #2</div>
            ...
            <div class="match">Match #15</div>
            <div class="match">Match #16</div>
        </div>
        <div class="round ro16">
            <div class="match">Match #17</div>
            ...
            <div class="match">Match #24</div>
        </div>
        <div class="round quarter">
            <div class="match">Match #25</div>
            <div class="match">Match #26</div>
            <div class="match">Match #27</div>
            <div class="match">Match #28</div>
        </div>
        <div class="round semi">
            <div class="match">Match #29</div>
            <div class="match">Match #30</div>
        </div>
        <div class="round">
            <div class="match">Match #31</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are looking for: a typical bracket setup.

However, it seems you have already achieved that!

Look at my screenshot of your jfiddle:

[image]

What browser are you using?  How does it look for you?  (I am using Chrome).

Comment: Its not like I want it :) I want the Match #17's center to be between Match #1 and Match #2. I want space between Match #17, #18, #19... Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ejQbb/ but without all the div.spacer's

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/qZaps/  So I have this so far, but one problem, I am having problems figuring out how to align the text to vertically centered.  I tried to display the unordered lists as table columns and have the lists displayed as table cells, but that doesn't work for some reason.  I'll figure it out, but I wanted to show you what I've done so far in the hopes that we both could work on it and figure out a solution.  I'm still working!  Let me know how you are doing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/mCpg6/  - From a Bracket Generator!  I'm looking to see how this worked now but please take a look!

Comment: Dont think that mCpg6 is that good. I mean its not really that dynamic. The whole idea of making my own bracket without the div.spacer's is to make it as dynamic as possible so that i dont have to include a css file depending on how many teams there's in the cup.